# How can I use Macros to analyze an interface output?

Tags: excel, vba, interface

I am currently trying to develop a VBA code to help me analyze how well an interface is working, the code has basically 2 main steps that I am having trouble with, the first one is to delete the rows that start with 300, 195 or 210 (this bit is working but I need to activate the macro at least 3 time to clear it all, so it is not looping correctly). this is the code I have for that bit:

```
Dim MyString As String
MyString = "300 , 195 , 210"
For X = 1 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Do  
If Replace(MyString, Left(Range("E" & X).value, 3), "") <> MyString Then Range("E" & X).EntireRow.Delete

Loop Until MyString <> "MyString"
```

The second part is a bit more tricky, the main information line may have from 1 up to 4 lines which are defined by how they start (if they start with 100 it's a new input, if it starts with 200 or 220 it is part of the 100 line that is shown above it). 
If there is more than 1 line for that input, I would need them to be in the same line (on the column to the right of the main one) so I can work with the data, but so far I have only been able to move the "additional lines" to another column:

```
Dim row As Long

For row = 2 To 99999
    ' Check if "save" appears in the value anywhere.
    If Range("E" & row).value Like "*220Z010*" Then
        ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
        Range("F" & row).value = Range("E" & row).value
        Range("E" & row).value = ""
    End If
        If Range("E" & row).value Like "*220Z020*" Then
        ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
        Range("G" & row).value = Range("E" & row).value
        Range("E" & row).value = ""
    End If
        If Range("E" & row).value Like "*200Z547*" Then
        ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
        Range("H" & row).value = Range("E" & row).value
        Range("E" & row).value = ""
    End If
        If Range("E" & row).value Like "*220Z030*" Then
        ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
        Range("H" & row).value = Range("E" & row).value
        Range("E" & row).value = ""
    End If
```

I tried to be as clear as possible, but please feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first part you need to rethink your loop. Remember that when it matches the deletion for, lets say, line 4, `i` will still have the value for line 4, and line 5 will move up, being the new 4, and getting skipped.

Comment: When deleting rows, as a rule, you should loop from the bottom up, and not top down, else your pointers get confused.

Comment: An example of your raw data, along with your desired output (and actual output), would help in understanding exactly what you are trying to do. Preferable **NOT** as a screenshot as it is not easy to transfer a screenshot into an Excel worksheet.  Either upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) that demonstrates your problem, or create a table in your question (if the data can be demonstrated without a huge table).

Comment: why in the world would you ever store numeric values as a substring??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below does what you describe, as best I can understand. I had to guess at what your raw data looked like, and as Ron Rosenfeld advised, if you provide your raw data and your desired output you'd be more likely to get the help you need.  But at least what I've provided here should get you started.

Notice that I've broken it up into 2 routines, as you described. The first routine removes the rows, and then the second routine moves the lines.  You didn't say if you wanted to deleted lines after moving them so I didn't. These routines assume your data has no gaps.

```
Sub main()
removeRows
moveLines
End Sub

Sub removeRows()
Dim r As Range, s As String, d() As Integer, num As Integer
Set r = Range("E1")
While r <> ""
  r.Select
  s = Left(r, 3)
  If s = "300" Or s = "195" Or s = "210" Then
    num = num + 1
    ReDim Preserve d(1 To num) As Integer
    d(num) = r.row
  End If
  Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
While num > 0
  Rows(d(num)).Delete
  num = num - 1
Wend
End Sub

Sub moveLines()
Dim r As Range, cell As Range, i As Integer, s As String
Set r = Range("E1")
Set r = Range(r, r.End(xlDown))
For Each cell In r
  cell.Select
  i = 0
  s = Left(cell, 3)
  If s = "100" Then
    Do
      i = i + 1
      s = Left(cell.Offset(i, 0), 3)
      If s = "200" Or s = "220" Then cell.Offset(0, i) = cell.Offset(i, 0)
    Loop Until s <> "200" And s <> "220"
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Here's the result I got in testing:
[image]

Comment: That was it! it worked like a charm, thank you very much!